# API Call Returns Numerous Sheets but None That I Need

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

My use case at high level is - get the sheet out of Smartsheet via API (with GET), transform data in a ETL tool and load into a relational db for further manipulation and reporting.

All I'm trying to do is retrieve data for sheets that have been shared with me (a couple as Viewer, 2 as Editor (cannot edit), 2 as Editor (can edit) and 2 as Owner).  I'm making a pretty basic API call to get a list of sheets https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets (with auth token and other header attrs) and the problem is that I'm getting all kinds of sheets back (~18,000) in the results but **none are the ones I need** (see above).

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

P.S. Using specific sheet IDs is not going to be feasible as I won't know them when extracting data anyways.  Another thing - I will be filtering out the sheets I don't need with the ETL tool's help anyways, just need to understand why the ones I'm after aren't coming back since I'm using the token of that user.

Answer (score 1):

The command `https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets?includeAll=true` will return every sheet that you can access.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.  ?includeAll=true would be nice, but I still have to paginate given the data volume.  I actually worked around this - went into the Smartsheet app/front-end and removed sharing for myself on all the workspaces with sheets I don't need for the extract.  Given that I'm using my own token it worked well.